# Ace Editor setAnnotations method only shows one error at a time

Tags: javascript, text-editor, ace-editor

I'm currently running an external plugin which detects code smells in the ace editor tab and I want to use setAnnotations to iterate through an array of line number and error message to highlight all of the errors. However only the last object in my array is being highlighted suggesting that once a second annotation is set, the previous one is wiped.

```
function highlightError(errorMsg, line){
editor.getSession().setAnnotations([{
    row: line-1,
    column: 10,
    text: errorMsg,
    type: "error" // also warning and information
}]);
```

}

This is the method i'm using to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

setAnnotations takes array of annotations, which replaces annotations from previous call, so you need to collect all annotations into array and call setAnnotations after that, once

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a JSON array that holds all the annotations and then set it to the editor.

```
//This array holds all the errors
var jsonErrorArray = [];

var errorLinesArray = [1,5, 7];
var errorMessagesArray = ["Error on line 1", "Error on line 5", "Error on line 7"];

for (var i = 0; i < errorLinesArray.length; i++) {
            jsonErrorArray[fileNamesArray[i]].push({
                row: errorLinesArray[i]-1,
                column: 10,
                type:"error",
                text: errorMessagesArray[i]
            });
        }

//Set the annotations to the editor
editor.getSession().setAnnotations(jsonErrorArray[currentFileName]);
```